# Calculating $\oint_C \vec F \cdot \mathrm d \vec r$ where $\vec F=\langle y^2,x\rangle$ and C:$x^2+4y^2=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

Calculating $\displaystyle \oint_C \vec F \cdot \mathrm d \vec r$ where $\vec F=\langle y^2,x\rangle$ and $ C: x^2+4y^2=4$

Making use of Green's theorem, I have rewritten the integral in the form of  $\displaystyle \int_D \left[\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right]\, \mathrm dA$ which comes out to be $$\int_D(1-2y)\, \mathrm dA$$ where $M=y^2$ and $ N=x$. After this, I am unable to write the limits of the double integral. I have tried to use the parametrization as $$x=\cos \theta \\y=2\sin \theta $$ So how do I go about the limits of $ \mathrm d \vec r$ and $\mathrm d\theta$ ? Or have I made a big blunder in some step above?? Please help.

Comment: Your curve $C$ is parameterized by $x = 2\cos t$ and $y = \sin t$. Is there a reason for applying Green's theorem rather than calculating the integral directly?

Comment: Do you really need it? You have a sum of two integrals. The first one is the area of $D$ (it is an ellips), and the second one is zero (because of the symmetry $y \to -y$).

Comment: $x = 2 r \cos t, y = r \sin t, 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. Jacobian is $2$. But please note that the integral of $y$ is zero over the region due to symmetry. So all you are left with is to find the area of the ellipse which you anyway know otherwise you can find through integral.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Question asked specifically. Oh Yes thanks for correcting my parameters!

Comment: @TimurBakiev Okay I see it

Comment: @MathLover Yes thanks timur has also pointed it out

Comment: Yes I saw it after I posted. Just on the other point, it is absolutely fine to use Green's theorem here even if the question did not specifically ask for it (unless they specifically asked for line integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you had with that parametrization is that you didn't normalize it:

$$x^2+4y^2=4\iff \frac{x^2}{2^2}+y^2=1\implies a=2\,,\,b=1\;\text{in the normal form}\;\;\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

so that the actually accurate parametrization results in what has already been commented:

$$\begin{cases}x=2\cos t\\{}\\y=\sin t\end{cases}\;\;\;,\;\;\;t\in[0,\,2\pi]\; .$$

And your line integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi}F(\gamma(t))\,\gamma'(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\langle \sin^2 t,2\cos t\rangle\cdot\langle-2\sin t,\cos t\rangle\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(-2\sin^3t+2\cos^2t)dt=\ldots$$

with $\;\gamma\;$ the parametrization.

Comment: I think given the correction in the comments OP could have worked this out for him/her self. Also the question regarded the double integral, not the line integral.

Comment: As commented, I just gave him an idea to do the line integral directly, without Green's Theorem.

Comment: Well I can use this to verify my answer. @UmbertoP.